# Two equivalent categories

Tags: category-theory

Let $f: A\to B$ be an appropriate functor of small categories. It induces a functor $f^*: Psh(A)\to Psh(B)$, whose left adjoint is $f_!$. Is it true that 
$$
Psh(A)\to Psh(B)/f_!(cst)
$$
an equivalence of categories? Where $cst$ is the constant presheaf on $A$ with value the single set (terminal presheaf), and $Psh(B)/f_!(cst)$ denotes the over category.

It is easy to check this for $A$ and $B$ are discrete categories, or sets. However if $B=*$, then the right hand side only remembers the information about objects.

Comment: There is no reason to expect it to be true. The last paragraph is already a counterexample.

Comment: @ZhenLin I am seeking for an "appropriate" condition to make this true. It does remember objects, then I would like to see what will happen if $f$ is faithful.

Comment: If $f$ arises from a closed subspace $X ⊂ Y$, then $f_∗$ is an equivalence between sheaves on $X$ and sheaves on $Y$ supported on $X$.

Comment: That's not true. The only kinds of continuous maps $f : X \to Y$ such that $\mathbf{Sh}(X) \to \mathbf{Sh}(Y)_{/ f_* 1}$ is an equivalence are local homeomorphisms.